# Getting friendly output status of FFMPEG transcode

Tags: bash, unix, ffmpeg

When I transcode a file using

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi  -vcodec libx264 output.mp4
```

the `ffmpeg` program will show the status of the file being transcoded bit by bit. It will fill up the screen and if I use a for loop to transcode multiple files, after a while I do not know which file it is up to.

Is there a way to update only the last line on the bash screen when it is transcoding?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, redirect ffmpeg output somewhere (to /dev/null or to a file) and print out only the name of the file that is currently being transcoded.

For example:

```
for input in file1 file2 file3
 do
  echo "Transcoding $input"
  ffmpeg -i $input  -vcodec libx264 transcoded_$input > /dev/null
 done
```